# SPARK SQL list_collect preserving order

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a table of two string columns (type, element), and for each *type*, I want to concatenate all of the *elements* on one row.

I can achieve this through the collect_list function:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("0", "p0"),
  ("0", "p2"),
  ("1", "p0"),
  ("1", "p8")
)).toDF("type", "element")

df.groupBy($"type")
  .agg(concat_ws(",", collect_list($"element")).alias("elements")).show

## +---------+---------------+
## | type    |       elements|
## +---------+---------------+
## |0        |p0,p2          |
## |1        |p0,p8          |
## +---------+---------------+
```

In this example the output preserves the order in which the *elements* where inserted but, is this premise always true? Or there is no guarantee that the elements are going to be concatenated in order? i.e. a different execution could lead to a different sequence among the *elements* list.
If the latter is true, how can I always preserve the order? Do I need a new column with an ordering index?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the order relation you wish to preserve ?

Comment: The element values: for instance, in this example, for type 0, I added : p0 and p8, hence I always want (p0,p8). If I had added p8 and then p0, then I would want (p8,p0).

Comment: @eliasah, The problem with the example in the o.p. is that it seems to assume that there is some implicit order on the dataframe rows, which i believe is wrong. A better example is to have a dtaframe with 3 or more columns. When the DF is grouped by one of the columns the other two can be "collect_listed" and then you can ask whether the order is preserved within the two lists for the other two columns. Meaning that elements that came from the same row in the other 2 cols end up at the same index in the two collected lists.

Comment: did you get the answer? I have the same doubt.